# Postgres MERGE insert without specifying columns

Tags: postgresql, merge

I want to use a Postgres (I am using 13.8, can update to 14 if required) merge statement to:

1. if matched, update the ID and CName of the record
2. if not matched, insert the whole record without specifying the column names

The source is a view of which the format is exactly the same.

```
MERGE INTO  my_table tgt
USING (SELECT * FROM my_view WHERE pk = 'ff57f523-470c-461e-a47a-70c35bccdff3') AS src
ON src.pk = tgt.pk
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET    ID = src.ID,
                CName = src.CName
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT
  VALUES (src.*);
```

Postgres does not like the below, I know you can not specify the columns after the INSERT, but is there a way to also avoid doing to after VALUES?

Thanks in advance for any assistance, I can't seem to find examples online.

I intend to wrap this inside a trigger function to propogate from a source system to a downstream legacy system (hence only a couple of fields) so if there are other suggestions such as dynamically generating the column names, that is an option.

Comment: Tip: change that `SELECT FROM my_view` to a CTE, **and add explicit column names** to it.

Comment: _"I know you can not specify the columns after the INSERT, but is there a way to also avoid doing to after VALUES?"_ - **why** are you wanting to know?

Comment: Postgres does/did not have the `Merge` statement. It was introduced in v15, released last week. In v13 you need the `on conflict` clause of the  [insert](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-insert.html) statement.  BTW you should **always** specify column names.

Comment: Merge doesn’t exist in your version, you need at least version 15.